# How can I traverse through autosuggestoptions using down and up arrow keys in Angular

Tags: angular

I have used keyup event to recognise the keys.

```
 else if(event.keyCode == 40){
                 //logic to traverse through options
                }
```

Can anyone please help me with the logic
I want to traverse through autosuggestion container when something is typed in search bar like in google . How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your question.
Check this example: page 223 on pdf (page 200 on real book) (https://www.nglesson.com/Livres/ng-book2-angular-5-r67.pdf) Hope it is help you!